# Altium Designer - Printout templates

Tags: pcb, altium

When i've to generate PDF files with printout layers, i must always add the missing layer i need. For example i  usually draw the board outline on keepout layer, so everytime i have to add the keepout layer on the printout set.
Is there any way to build a custom template with all the printout layer and load it at once?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible.You can create your Output job file and use it as a template. 
Once you create Output job file as you wish, just add it in your project as Add existing to Project.

Comment: Thankyou. I've always thought must create new output job for each project.